# Are there any default security settings I should be worried about in windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 (via Rackspacecloud) and now that I'm going live I'm just curious if there are any security settings I should "turn on" or other settings I should tinker with to make it 90~95% secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should harden your installation, Microsoft has a [Security Guide for Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fb8b981f-227c-4af6-a44b-b115696a80ac&displaylang=en) (which also applies to R2). See the additional resources on that page as well for more information, especially the Solution Accelerators.